# Check NSArray is sorted

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, sorting

I have an `NSMutabaleArray` and I want to check it whether it would be in **sorted mode** or not after insertion of any element. So what would be the **fastest** technique to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one loop to traverse and check if `array[i+1]` is greater than `array[i]`th element, assuming array is sorted in ascending order. If this fails then its not sorted. This would be O(n).

By using Cocoa- library:
Typical answer would be to sort it again, if it is already sorted then that would be quick, not much of time and space complexity.Then compare the two arrays, if both matches then your array was sorted.

**EDIT:**
The above is an example for integers. If objects (Cocoa objects) are there, then you need to decide what kind of values you want to compare, if string then need to check `NSOrderedDescending`, `NSOrderedSam`e , for `NSDate` `isGreater` etc.

Comment: Ya I thought of that but I was thinking for some different and less complex **IF EXISTS** as I am new to Objective C

Comment: @kamaldeepsinghbhatia: No other way in Cocoa.

Comment: Ok then. Thank you 

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I didn't get it. Are you saying this statement will return true or false even if the array has strings in it? if (array[i+1] > array[i])?

Comment: @SamB: That was an example for `integers`., If other objects are there, then you need to decide what kind of values you want to compare, if string then need to check `NSOrderedDescending`, `NSOrderedSame `, for date `isGreater` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this (as I have a String array)

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.count; i++)
    if ([array[i - 1] compare:array[i]] != NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;
return YES;
```

So this code returns me a BOOL value when I call the function.